# I can't convert Textbox.Text to int

Tags: c#, wpf

```
int InvoerEieren = Convert.ToInt32(txtInvoerEieren.Text);
```

while txt.InvoerEieren.Text is an Textbox with a random number user can put (1 - 999).

This is what I get when computer runs that line of code.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

I also have tried using "int.Parse()" function.

---

edit:

When I create a new function with this code:

```
int eenGetal = Convert.ToInt32(txtInvoerEieren.Text);
            MessageBox.Show(eenGetal.ToString());
```

it's working, that's weird... why isn't it working for other function?

Comment: Does the user enter a number from 1 until 999 or `"1 - 999"`(f.e. to specify a range or a subtraction).

Comment: If you debug, I think you will find that `txtInvoerEieren.Text` does nto contain the number, at least not just the number. If it did, you would not get the exception.

Comment: Run this in the debugger. Put a breakpoint on the line above. What is *really* in txtInvoerEieren.Text?

Comment: `Int32.TryParse(txtInvoerEieren.Text, out InvoerEieren)`

Comment: what exactly is the content of the `txtInvoerEieren.Text`?

Comment: Are you using punctuation in your Textbox?

Comment: What I mean with "Random input" is a number between 1 to infinite. So, "453" may been the input of txtInvoereieren.Text, So no letters or special characters.

Comment: @OnedZair - Including decimals, so for example 4.23? Or when you say infinite, I could put in 39204898593248?

Comment: @OnedZair even no white spaces?

Comment: why are you using a textbox and not a numericUpDown-Control?

Comment: @ØyvindKnobloch-Bråthen Well yea, if it is possible, yes. But I rather want to see smal numbers like under the 1000.

Comment: I'm 100% sure of no white-spaces.

Comment: Is there a specific reason for using a `TextBox`?
I would suggest using a `numericUpDown`-`Control`.
http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=NumericUpDown&referringTitle=Home

Comment: Its probably not an int that is being input then. Have you tried to int32 or int64 or double etc???

Comment: @OnedZair Please post the exact value you are using when you get this error.

Comment: Fine then.. Please assign the text box value to the string variable itself and check if a value is being fetched correctly. If it is fine, then you will not face any issue in parsing in to an INT

Comment: Check this image, this is what I get while debugging: http://s16.postimage.org/4h2p8n18z/Knipsel1.png

Comment: You should add `txtInvoerEieren.Text` to the watch list, that's what's important.

Comment: @AntonieBlom: He hasn't shown us a value so that we could reproduce the issue. That's the reason why the question's quality is poor not the search effort(what would you search for?).

Comment: @Oned: Btw, is your namespace really called `_12EiDenoH`? :-O

Comment: @Groo No, I don't know why it's that. Oh wait it is _12EiDenoH..

Comment: When I do this:

int eenGetal = Convert.ToInt32(txtInvoerEieren.Text);
            MessageBox.Show(eenGetal.ToString()); it is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a `Debug.WriteLine(txtInvoerEieren.Text);`
See if it is what you think it is.

It is a textbox.
If you don't assign a value then will be null or string.empty.
Both null and string.empty will fail that Int parse.
As in the comment use

```
Int32.TryParse(txtInvoerEieren.Text, out InvoerEieren)
```

You can bind to Int? 
But you will need to use a converter to convert string.empty to null.
And you will need to handle keydown and not allow anything but digits. 
Handle keydown will not deal with sting.empty that has to be a converter. 
Well this is the only way I was able to bind to an Int.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that what is inside the textbox can't be converted to an int. an int represent a whole number, and cannot have any decimal spaces.

So you can use 1, 5 ,34 but not 1,23 or 4.54. In addition you cannot use numbers larger than +/-2,147,483,647.

if you need larger numbers, use `long` instead ( and then `long.Parse`). If you need to have decimal points use `decimal` (and `decimal.Parse`). Note that if you are parsing decimals, you have to take the culture into consideration since you have to use the correct decimal marker according to the culture you are using with `decimal.Parse`.

And since it's user input you should consider using the `TryParse` variants instead, since they won't "blow up" if the user gives an incorrect input (ie. Non-numeric).

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the Int32.TryParse method.
If the in value is invalid format, or just text it should be handling exceptions internally and returning you a zero value.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to convert a string to Double, you should use the [Double.TryParse Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1.aspx) to parse the value because it wraps a try/catch around the conversion for you.

```
 double decimalValue;
 bool success = Double.TryParse(txtInvoerEieren.Text, out decimalValue);
 if(success) { Debug.WriteLine("Successful parsing to Double!"); }
 else { Debug.WriteLine("Parsing to Double failed!"); }
```

Similar for converting to Int32 values, you should use [Int32.TryParse Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx)

```
 int decimalValue;
 bool success = Int32.TryParse(txtInvoerEieren.Text, out decimalValue);
 if(success) { Debug.WriteLine("Successful parsing to Int32!"); }
 else { Debug.WriteLine("Parsing to Int32 failed!"); }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure whether the user has typed in a text representing a correct number, I would suggest you to use another conversion method that checks the validity of the number

```
int InvoerEieren;
if (Int32.TryParse(txtInvoerEieren.Text, out InvoerEieren)) {
    Console.WriteLine("The number is {0}", InvoerEieren);
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("\"{0}\" cannot be converted to int!", 
                      txtInvoerEieren.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `Int32.TryParse` instead of `Int32.Parse` -

```
int InvoerEieren;
Int32.TryParse(txtInvoerEieren.Text, out InvoerEieren);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is some wrong input, this should never have happened. Although you can change this by adding a KeyPress event on this textbox. you can do this adding these line in your event handler function:

```
        if (char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar))
        {
            e.Handled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Number");
            e.Handled = true;
        }
```

I think this should solve your problem.